# Public Group Members Don't Get Emails or Calendar Invitations

Tags: groups, distribution-lists

I have a public group on my company's Sharepoint site. The first time I created a calendar event on the group's calendar it sent Outlook invitations to all the members, as expected.

I'm not aware of having changed anything but now the members don't receive invitations when I create events on the group calendar, even when the box is checked to 'send a meeting invitation to group members'. They also don't receive invitations or emails sent to the group email address from my personal Outlook account.

I'm not a Sharepoint admin for the company, just for my group. Is there a configuration setting that enables the group distribution list for emails and calendar invitations that might have gotten turned off? Is there something I can tell our Sharepoint admins that will help them fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you email the users from Outlook, I'm thinking that an administrator may have stopped outbound email to external domains.

Comment: No, emailing the group is not working either, so that's a distinct possibility. I've opened a ticket with them to see what they can find out.